# Stop 'localhost' resolving to old domain name? (or, how to change 'live' wordpress site back to local?)

Tags: apache2, dns, wordpress

I had a wordpress site running on an Ubuntu 18.04 linux server. The server died (motherboard issue) and I've since been able to take the hard drive out and boot from it on a different computer.  My goal is to get into the wordpress site to use Duplicator to make a full backup (stupidly, I had not done this at all recently).

I *thought* that I could just go to http://localhost/ on a browser to see the wordpress site, but the browser keeps redirecting to my.domain.edu which is now assigned to a different computer.

I have already tried changing the hostname to something else, it still does this.

How do I stop this? Or rather, how do I get into the wordpress site in this situation?? Please help!

Comment: Do you have an entry in /etc/hosts that points localhost to my.domain.edu? And does it do the same thing if you navigate to 127.0.0.1 (localhost as an IP address).

Comment: No, I removed it. So now /etc/hosts just has `127.0.0.1 localhost` and then some ipv6 things that I didn't understand and just left (none says anything like the old domain name though.)  And yes, 127.0.0.1 does the same.